Does granting execute stored procedures (all) implicitly allow any critical privileges?
Does granting execute stored procedures (all) implicitly allow any critical privileges? For example privilege to control security, etc, by runing the relevant stored procs?
The way to grant execute all stored procedures is:
GRANT EXECUTE TO [user]


Can you provide an example of what you are asking?

GRANT EXECUTE TO [user]

I do know how to give execute access to a user but what do you mean by privilege to control security?

Basically allowing to run all SPs means they can run things like sp_addrolemember and thereby impact security?

The answer to your question is No.
It is documented in this Microsoft document.

Limitations and restrictions
You cannot use SQL Server Management
Studio to grant permissions on system procedures or system functions.
Use GRANT Object Permissions instead.

You can test this with the code below. I tested in SQL 2022 CU13.
--create a test database
USE [master];
GO
CREATE DATABASE [test]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'test', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'test_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 WITH LEDGER = OFF;
GO

--create two logins
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [testgrantexecute] WITH PASSWORD=N'testgrantexecute', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
GO
CREATE LOGIN [testgrantexecute1] WITH PASSWORD=N'testgrantexecute1', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
GO

--create user from the two logins
USE [test]
GO
CREATE USER [testgrantexecute] FOR LOGIN [testgrantexecute];
GO
CREATE USER [testgrantexecute1] FOR LOGIN [testgrantexecute1];
GO

--create a stored procedure
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [a] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,   [b] [int] NULL, [c] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [a] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx] ON [dbo].[test]
(
    [c] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE proc [dbo].[sp1] @a int
as
BEGIN
    select * from  dbo.test  where c=@a  order by b
END
GO

--Grant execute on all to user testgrantexecute
GRANT EXECUTE TO [testgrantexecute];
GO

--Execute as user testgrantexecute
EXECUTE AS USER ='testgrantexecute'
--can execute user create stored procedure
EXEC test.dbo.sp1 @a=100;
GO
--cannot execute system stored procedure
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'testgrantexecute1';
GO
REVERT;

--cleanup
USE [master]
GO
DROP DATABASE [test]
GO

